# ctypes objects at very similar memory address

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes

I was debugging another project, when I recognized this funny behaviour:

If I generate two c callables from python callables they are always at very similar locations:

```
from ctypes import *

def foo():
    print("foo")
def bar():
    print("bar")
c_cm=CFUNCTYPE(c_voidp)

c_foo=c_cm(foo)
print(c_foo)
c_bar=c_cm(bar)
print(c_bar)
```

running this a few times:

```
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f8ddb65d048>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f8ddb65d110>

<CFunctionType object at 0x7f40a022e048>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f40a022e110>

<CFunctionType object at 0x7fa1f1fb1048>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7fa1f1fb1110>
```

the `7f` is not the interesting part, but the `048` and `110`.

Does this mean, that my program is always located at a very similar place in *ram*?

**info**: I am on *linux 3.18.x*

Comment: BTW, the name `c_voidp` is deprecated. Please use `c_void_p` in new code.

Comment: @eryksun make an answer and I will upvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CPython's small-object allocator uses 256 KB arenas, divided into 4 KB pools, in which a given pool is dedicated to a particular allocation size (ranging from 8 to 512 bytes, in steps of 8). The lower 3 hexadecimal digits (12 bits) of the address are the object offset into the pool. This design is discussed in extensive comments in [Objects/obmalloc.c](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Objects/obmalloc.c#l431).

In the case of 64-bit Linux, a ctypes function pointer object is 200 (0xc8) bytes, i.e. `sys.getsizeof(c_bar) == 200`, so a pool holds 20 function pointers. Note that the first allocated object in the pool is at offset 0x048 instead of 0x000. The pool itself has an initial header (`pool_header`) that's 48 (0x030) bytes, plus each ctypes object has a garbage collection header (`PyGC_Head`) that's 24 (0x018) bytes. Without the GC header, a ctypes function pointer is 176 bytes (0x0b0). Thus the next function pointer's GC header is at offset 0x0f8, with the object proper starting 24 bytes later at offset 0x110.

You can print out a bunch to see the pattern, once it starts allocating from completely free pools. For example, `funcs = [c_cm(foo) for i in range(10000)][-40:];` `idx = 0; while id(funcs[idx]) & 0xfff != 0x048: idx +=1;` `print(*[funcs[n] for n in range(idx, idx+20)], sep='\n')`:

```
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df048>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df110>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df1d8>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df2a0>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df368>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df430>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df4f8>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df5c0>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df688>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df750>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df818>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df8e0>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3df9a8>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3dfa70>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3dfb38>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3dfc00>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3dfcc8>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3dfd90>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3dfe58>
<CFunctionType object at 0x7f66ca3dff20>
```

Note that the function pointer object's base address that's printed in the repr has nothing directly to do with the address that gets passed to a C library. A function pointer object (i.e. [`PyCFuncPtrObject`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h#l75)) has a `b_ptr` field that points at a buffer that holds the actual function address that gets passed to C. You can inspect this value by creating a `void *` pointer from the function pointer, e.g. `addr_bar = c_void_p.from_buffer(c_bar).value`. For a callback, ctypes allocates a block of executable memory in which it writes a bit of code that sets up calling [`closure_fcn`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Modules/_ctypes/callbacks.c#l289) to call the target Python function. This is a [`CThunkObject`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v3.5.0/Modules/_ctypes/ctypes.h#l59), which is referenced (kept live) as, for example, `c_foo._objects['0']`.

Answer (score 2):

The least significant digits are the same, but observe that the digits in the middle are not. So, your program is moving around in memory on different runs, but there's some kind of code page alignment going on, such that the addresses always start at a multiple of 4096. Not really surprising.

Comment: that is just, what I wanted to hear, a _code page alignment_.